# Basename removes the second file of my 'find' list in bash

Tags: bash, shell, find

I have run into an issue when using `basename` on a list of files found with `find`.
For some reason, `basename` decides to delete the second item of the `find` list when there are only two files to be found.

```
gas$ ls -l
total 8
-rwxrwxrwx  1 gas  staff  54 Feb 26 19:00 find_sh.sh
-rw-r--r--  1 gas  staff   0 Feb 26 19:21 test-file.sh

gas$ find . -type f -name '*.sh'
./find_sh.sh
./test-file.sh

gas$ basename $(find . -type f -name '*.sh')
find_sh.sh
```

> Adding a third file seems to fix it for an obscure reason (see below)

```
gas$ touch test-file2.sh
gas$ basename $(find . -type f -name '*.sh')
find_sh.sh
test-file.sh
test-file2.sh
```

Does anybody know what happens for the basename of the second file? I'm currious about what's going wrong.

> I have found as a solution to ditch `basename` and simply use a `sed 's/.*\///'` to remove the path in the name.

So even if I found a solution, I'm still curious about what's going wrong with `basename` when there are two files to be displayed :)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check the manual page for `basename`. If you want to use multiple file names at once, you need the `-a` option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need basename at all, find is capable on its own:

```
find . -type f -name '*.sh' -printf '%f\n'
```

---

The reason your 2 argument form of basename is not working like you expect is because that's how the 2 argument form of basename works. From the man page:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> > basename NAME [SUFFIX]
> >         basename OPTION... NAME...

When given no options, the 2nd argument is the suffix to strip off of the first argument.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation, this answers exactly my question!